# Tomcat server accessible only inside the server

Tags: tomcat

I have installed Tomcat7 on a dedicated server running CentOS. It is configured to run in port 80. I am able to verify it running and browsing both localhost and local IP 192.168.1.230 are working fine. The server does not have a firewall installed. But I am not able to access it from another system in the same network using the local IP address. Pinging this server from another machine in the network itself is not working.

Comment: *Pinging this server from another machine in the network itself is not working.* -> that sounds like a networking problem and not a Tomcat isue

Comment: Or an installed firewall. That is crappy configured, on top.